# How to save clipboard text directly to file?

Tags: macos, copy-paste

I have huge text data in clipboard that has been copied using Cmd + C. Now I want to directly save the text in a file. If I open vi/vim and paste it takes long time as rendered to the vi UI. Is there any way to save this clipboard text directly to a file in harddisk?